# I see scapy ipsec.py python code in GitHub: how do I install and use it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, github, scapy, gitpython

There is a python module to generate IPSec packets using scapy in GitHub, but that file is not in its own `.git` extension to download.

Please find the link for the code:https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/scapy/layers/ipsec.py

How can I use that script?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you would need to clone the full repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/secdev/scapy
cd scapy
```

From there, you can have [access to the interactive shell](https://github.com/secdev/scapy#interactive-shell):

```
sudo ./run_scapy 
Welcome to Scapy
>>> p = IP(dst="github.com")/ICMP()
>>> r = sr1(p)
Begin emission:
.Finished to send 1 packets.
```

That would include all scapy features, including ipsec:

```
>>> sa = SecurityAssociation(ESP, spi=0xdeadbeef, crypt_algo='AES-CBC',
...                          crypt_key='sixteenbytes key')
>>> p = IP(src='1.1.1.1', dst='2.2.2.2')
>>> p /= TCP(sport=45012, dport=80)
>>> p /= Raw('testdata')
>>> p = IP(raw(p))
>>> p
```

Comment: In the interactive shell i am able to generate IPsec packet, but if the same is imported in file mode(from scapy.layers.ipsec import CryptAlgo). I am getting the following error                                    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ipsec.py", line 2, in <module>
    sa = SecurityAssociation(ESP, spi=0xdeadbeef, crypt_algo='NULL',crypt_key='sixteenbytes key')
NameError: name 'SecurityAssociation' is not defined